# Reload Puppet gem provider source

Tags: puppet, ruby, rubygems

So I've got Puppet Enterprise 2.7 on a "master" node, puppetentmaster.  While working to craft new recipes for installing Ruby 2.0 on a "client" node, I noticed if I forced the client to begin using gem 2.0 I would run into errors like:

```
err: /Stage[main]/_ruby::Mysql_gem/Package[mysql]/ensure: change from absent to 2.8.1 failed: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/gem install -v 2.8.1 --include-dependencies --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql' returned 1: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --include-dependencies
 at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/ci/modules/_ruby/manifests/mysql_gem.pp:29
```

I traced the `--include-dependencies` to https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/commit/2284e837939628f81149e62fdc0f314ff077a776, it has since been removed, so I removed it from my Puppet provider code on the master in `/opt/puppet/lib/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/provider/package/gem.rb`:

```
  def install(useversion = true)
    command = [command(:gemcmd), "install"]
    command << "-v" << resource[:ensure] if (! resource[:ensure].is_a? Symbol) and useversion
    # JOE HAS BEEN HERE - see http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/19741,
    # https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/commit/2284e837939628f81149e62fdc0f314ff077a776
    # Always include dependencies
    # command << "--include-dependencies"
```

Unfortunately the code for `gem.rb` is inexplicably cached somewhere - I've restarted every service I can think to restart to no avail, I *still* get the `--include-dependencies` option included.

How does one force that provider code to get reloaded on the master to take out the `--include-dependencies` when using the `gem` provider?

Comment: Have you tried changing this on the client instead of the master?

Comment: That is the answer.  What I ended up doing is created a patch file in my Puppet code to patch the client `gem.rb` prior to using `update-alternatives`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the source on the puppet client, not the master.